# Find command in Command substitution bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Hope you are doing well. I am kind of new to bash scripting so I wanted to ask you a question on something I stumbled upon just recently when I was playing around with the find command. What I had noticed was that when I search for a script name using the find command using the command substitution in the bash script, and call the variable from command substitution, it will find the script full path and also execute it right after. Can you please let me know why and how this is working?
E.g.

```
SEARCH=$(find / -type f -iname "script.name" 2> /dev/null)
$SEARCH
```

Regards

Comment: The question is unclear.  `find` prints the full path of the script and assigns it to `SEARCH`.  The line `$SEARCH` executes the script.

Comment: Hi William, Thanks you very much for the reply. I just wanted to know why the '$SEARCH' would execute the command from the find command.

Comment: If `$SEARCH` expands to `/path/to/script`, then writing `$SEARCH` is (basically) the same as writing `/path/to/script`.  `bash` parses the line and attempts to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Bash performs expansions before it builds and executes the command. If you execute `cd "$HOME"` for example, you probably want to go to the directory stored in the variable HOME and not to a directory literally named $HOME. This allows you to put a command name inside a variable and run it by expanding the variable as the first word, although this [isn't really recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) because it becomes very complex to manage for anything more than the simplest commands. The code in your question would probably not work as intended if `find` returned multiple results for example.

See [BashParser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) on the BashFAQ.

Comment: Hi tjm, Thank you very much for the reply. Your answer makes a perfect sense.